# Problem with using importcsv module in yii framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to use importcsv module in yii framework as per documentation here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/importcsv/

After installing the module, I tried using it by going to the url http://localhost/index.php?r=importcsv/default/

I got the page to import csv file. When I clicked on the import csv button and chose a csv file, I get the following error:

============================

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
21/07/2011 4:26:41 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

=====

I could not find any help about this error. Had anyone used this module in yii framework successfully. Please let me know some clue on where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: is that the right url? shouldn't it be http://localhost/index.php?r=importcsv/default/

Comment: Yes right.. its a typo its localhost/index.php?=importcsv/default

Answer (score 2):

This module has given many horrors to install.

What worked for me was going into the module/importcsv/assets folder and opening the download.js file.

At line 8 I changed the action url to:

```
'?r=importcsv/default/upload',
```

the module I think assumes you have urlManager in the config/main.php file turned on.

If you are using a WAMP server on windows it might be best to take urlManager off and change the action url to the one i've posted above.